# How do I make a userform populate as soon as I press the button to open it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a useform that uses a form, but it only populates when I click the 'clear' button.

```
Private sub userform1_Initialize()
'stuff populating a page
```

Then on the same page, I have:

```
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
Call UserForm1_Initialize
End Sub
```

How do I go about using:

```
Call UserForm1_Initialize
```

somewhere that populates my form when the form pops up?

I tried putting it in the button to open the form (third line):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Show 
UserForm1_Initialize
End Sub
```

But I get the error:

```
Compile error: 

Sub or Function not defined.
```

I tried putting my initialize code in the module instead of in the form, but I get the error:

```
Run-time error '424'

Object Required
```

I can't put the entire code in the module, because it will not know where to look for cells, right? What am I doing wrong?
I also tried using public instead of private. Same error as above.

Thank you!

Comment: It's very hard to decypher what you're asking... Why not give the relevant code block, and comment in what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: Have you looked at [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/initialize-event) about initializing userforms?

Comment: Are you sure about `UserForm1_Initialize`? The event should be `UserForm_Initialize` without the 1.

Comment: If the button that calls the user form is coded in a different module / area, it can't have access to the private sub that is within the code for userform1... If this is the case, try making initialize a public sub or create another public sub that calls initialize that can act as a middle man.

Comment: @VincentG I'd add that as an answer.  Didn't even see it when I first looked at the question - no wonder the `Initialize` event doesn't fire; it doesn't exist - just a procedure called `UserForm1_Initialize` - might as well have called it `FillMyForm`

Comment: Thank you @VincentG, that was the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of my code to activate a userform from my main macro:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Then, the code for the userform itself (right-click UserForm1, then "View Code"):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ListBox1.List = ProgramScale
End Sub
```

This populates the listbox on the form automatically when the form appears.

I think Vincent G is right in the comments above in that the sub title for your userform should not have the form number in it, e.g. UserForm_Initialize *not* UserForm1_Initialize().

Comment: My problem was that I using the userform's name instead of UserForm_Initialize().